# How can I match the value and assign to them a new column based on other column string

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe:

| MovieID | movieCater | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action, Comedy, Adventure | 4 |
| 2 | Action, Crime | 3 |
| 3 | Crime | 2 |

What I want:

| MovieID | movieCater | Action | Comedy | Adventure | Crime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Action, Comedy, Adventure | 4 | 4 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | Action, Crime | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | Crime | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: First you need to split your string to get the values from the movieCater field, then you normalize and finally pivot - you can read the Pivot documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for the column `movieCater` and multiply the rating:

```
out = df.join(df['movieCater'].str.get_dummies(",").mul(df['rating'],axis=0))
```

---

```
print(out)

   MovieID               movieCater  rating  Action  Adventure  Comedy  Crime
0        1  Action,Comedy,Adventure       4       4          4       4      0
1        2             Action,Crime       3       3          0       0      3
2        3                    Crime       2       0          0       0      2
```

To match the expected output, drop the rating column before joining:

```
out = (df.drop("rating",1).join(
      df['movieCater'].str.get_dummies(",").mul(df['rating'],axis=0))
```

If the series is very very big, you might also consider splitting the strings with the sep="," then use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51420716/9840637 to get the dummies. Finally multiply the rating column.

Comment: hi, i updated the question and add images for question, however, I don't know how to display the description, maybe you check my question by editing

Comment: @Leo - need `out = df.join(df['movieCater'].str.join(',').str.get_dummies(",").mul(df['rating'],axis=0))` ?

Comment: @anky - For second solution `df.join(df['movieCater'].str.get_dummies(",").mul(df.pop('rating'),axis=0))` should working

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) method.

First of all, you have to convert `movieCater` column to a list using [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

```
>>> df
   MovieID                 movieCater  rating
0        1  Action, Comedy, Adventure       4
1        2              Action, Crime       3
2        3                      Crime       2
>>> df.assign(movieCater_list = df['movieCater'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', ')))
   MovieID                 movieCater  rating              movieCater_list
0        1  Action, Comedy, Adventure       4  [Action, Comedy, Adventure]
1        2              Action, Crime       3              [Action, Crime]
2        3                      Crime       2                      [Crime]
```

Next, use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method on the `movieCater_list` column.

```
>>> df.assign(movieCater_list = df['movieCater'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))).explode('movieCater_list')
   MovieID                 movieCater  rating movieCater_list
0        1  Action, Comedy, Adventure       4          Action
0        1  Action, Comedy, Adventure       4          Comedy
0        1  Action, Comedy, Adventure       4       Adventure
1        2              Action, Crime       3          Action
1        2              Action, Crime       3           Crime
2        3                      Crime       2           Crime
```

Finally use [`.pivot_table()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
>>> df.assign(movieCater_list = df['movieCater'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))).explode('movieCater_list').pivot_table(values='rating', index=['MovieID', 'movieCater'], columns='movieCater_list', fill_value=0)
movieCater_list                    Action  Adventure  Comedy  Crime
MovieID movieCater
1       Action, Comedy, Adventure       4          4       4      0
2       Action, Crime                   3          0       0      3
3       Crime                           0          0       0      2
```

Comment: hi, i updated the question and add images for question, however, I don't know how to display the description, maybe you check my question by editing.

Comment: Just checked your edit. Using `pd.get_dummies()` from anky's solution is a better solution for your problem.  `.pivot_table()` relies on aggregation (`mean` by default) and causes problems when there are possible duplicates in `index` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution you can try out, first `split` based on delimiter then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) finally [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html#pandas-pivot)

```
print(
    df.assign(movieCater=df['movieCater'].str.split(","))
        .explode(column='movieCater')
        .pivot_table(index='MovieID', columns='movieCater', values='rating', fill_value=0)
)
```

---

```
movieCater  Action  Adventure  Comedy  Crime
MovieID                                     
1                4          4       4      0
2                3          0       0      3
3                0          0       0      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the input dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'MovieID': ['001','002','003'], 
    'movieCat': ['Action, Comedy, Adventure', 'Action, Crime', 'Crime'], 
    'rating': [4,3,2]
    })

#output
    MovieID movieCat                    rating
0   001     Action, Comedy, Adventure   4
1   002     Action, Crime               3
2   003     Crime                       2
```

I've re-use similar codes of @sushanth to get the final table

```
df['temp'] = df['movieCat'].str.split(", ")
df = df.explode(column='temp').pivot_table(index=['MovieID', 'movieCat'], columns='temp', values='rating', fill_value=0)
df.columns.name=None
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

#output
    MovieID movieCat                    Adventure   Comedy  Crime   Action
0   001     Action, Comedy, Adventure   4           4       0       4
1   002     Action, Crime               0           0       3       3
2   003     Crime                       0           0       2       0
```

After this you could export the table to Excel

```
df.to_excel('my_file.xlsx', index=False)
```